# User-specified number of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, arraylist

Okay, coding so far:

Main Class

```
public class Ticket
{
    // Method : Display the ticket details and the list of Lucky Dip numbers to the screen.
    public void displayTicket()
    {        
        numbersClass.populateArray();

        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        System.out.println("**           Lotto Ticket            **");
        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        numbersClass.ticket();
        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        System.out.println("***************************************");
    }
}
```

Uses Class

```
public class Numbers
{
    // Fields
    public int[] numberLine;
    public int randomNumber;
    public Random randomGen;


    // Constructor : Initialise number array
    public Numbers()
    {
        numberLine = new int[6];
        randomNumber = 0;
        randomGen = new Random();
    }

    // Method : Generate 6 random numbers in a range 1 to 49
    public void populateArray()
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < numberLine.length; index++)
        {
            randomNumber = 1 + randomGen.nextInt(49);
            numberLine[index] = randomNumber;
        }
        Arrays.sort(numberLine);
    }

    // Method : Format and display 6 numbers to the screen  
    public void ticket()
    {
        System.out.print("**         ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberLine.length; i++) 
        {
            if (numberLine[i] < 10) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(numberLine[i] + " ");
        }
    System.out.print("        **\n");
    }
 }
```

Running the displayTicket method on the Ticket Class will produce this:

```
***************************************
**                                   **
**           Lotto Ticket            **
**                                   **
***************************************
**                                   **
**         nn nn nn nn nn nn         **
**                                   **
***************************************
```

'n' being a randomly generated number between 1 and 49.

My question is how would I go about modifying this code in order to print out a user specified number of randomly generated number lines to produce this:

```
***************************************
**                                   **
**           Lotto Ticket            **
**                                   **
***************************************
**                                   **
**         nn nn nn nn nn nn         **
**         nn nn nn nn nn nn         **
**         nn nn nn nn nn nn         **
**                                   **
***************************************
```

EDIT:
So something like:

```
for(int index = 0; index < numberOfLines; index++)
        {
            numbersClass.populateArray();
            numbersClass.ticket();
        }
```

ought to do it? When using numberOfLines as a parameter for displayTicket.

Comment: Please tag as homework if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have your display ticket method take n (entered by user).

Run numbersClass.ticket(); in a for loop n number of times.

That should solve the issue.

Comment: No, that would produce the same numbers on 'n' number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remember the numbers in arrays for something else, then you could use an 2 dimensional array.  Otherwise, just print as they are generated.